# Salesforce - Restoring big objects

Tags: metadata, big-object

I'm trying to retrieve the data from certain big objects. The documentation seems to underline a different behavior on the data:

> Do not use the Id field in a query. Including Id in a query returns
>   only results that have an empty ID (000000000000000 or
>   000000000000000AAA).

In order to restore the data, the requirement is to check if the data is to be inserted/updated and the presence had to be checked. Generally, any object restore would be pivoting on the ID field. Here, all the Ids of the object is empty ID.

There seems to be a solution to get the indexed fields and check for the presence using the metadata type "[Index](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_infrastructure_indexes.htm)". Currently using the listMetadataCall on the metadata type "Index" and filtering on the object name to get the list of indices here. Are there any other efficient ways of querying this info?

Secondly, I'm thinking of detecting the presence of the record based on this indexed field before deciding to insert or update the data. Is this the right approach for the objects that have "Empty ID"s?